# I changed the structure of my site to reach index cards

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Excuse me for my english.
I make a brands directory web site.
Before to acces to the brands pages I use requests like this :

```
mydomain.com/fiche.php?id=115
```

where id is the id of the brand in my directory

I change the structure of the brands pages and now use this request:

```
mydomain.com/annuaire.php?type=fiche&id_marq=115
```

where `id` has become `id_marq`

I try to use a rewritebrule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^fiche.php$ http://www.annuaire-sites-officiels.com/annuaire.php?detail=fiche&id_marq=$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

to redirect the old links to the new pages but result dont pass the id_marq value and the url is:

```
http://www.annuaire-sites-officiels.com/annuaire.php?detail=fiche&id_marq=&id=115
```

**&id=** is too.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

### Check out Regex Back Reference Availability:

[image: Apache Back references]

You have to capture the query string. `[QSA]` passes it forward unaltered, so unless you're using `id` for anything you don't need that bit of code. Your [301 redirect](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) is correct since this is a permanent redirect. *Remember if you add a failed redirect your browser may cache that redirect so it might not look like it's working.*

In this string match I'm only catching numbers to prevent someone from passing something like an asterisk `*` and XSS exploiting your site.

I've not included and `[NC]` matches in my code because when you allow multiple cases they can seem like different URLs to search engines (bad for SEO).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^fiche.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/annuaire.php?detail=fiche&id_marq=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot AbsoluteƵERØ, your code is perfect. My 301 redirect is correct, its permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is not evaluating query string and that's why its not capturing `id` query parameter.

Change your code to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^fiche\.php$ /annuaire.php?detail=fiche&id_marq=%1 [R=302,L,QSA,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.